# Ionic. TypeError: unsupported proxy protocol

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I've installed Node, cordova and ionic CLI.
but when I try to start new ionic project there's error:

```
TypeError: unsupported proxy protocol: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    at mapOptsToProxy (C:\Users\DESIGN-00\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:112:11)
    at new ProxyAgent (C:\Users\DESIGN-00\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:150:17)
    at ProxyAgent (C:\Users\DESIGN-00\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\proxy-agent\index.js:145:45)
    at Request.proxy (C:\Users\DESIGN-00\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-proxy\node_modules\superagent-proxy\index.js:71:15)
    at C:\Users\DESIGN-00\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\http.js:46:17
    at next (native)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\DESIGN-00\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:104:62)
```

I've set npm config proxy but not work.
any suggest? 
Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Make sure you have installed Node.js , If not you can download it from below link

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Note: Setup environment variables if node in windows (If any error showing like npm not found

Step 2:

Install cordova using following command(In  command prompt in any local disk)

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Step 3:

Create a  new folder and open it, then press Ctrl+shift+F10 and click open command prompt windows here and type

```
ionic start myfirstproject blank
```

Comment: i've already install node.js, cordova, and ionic. problem is, in my office computer connect to local proxy.. i try setup proxy with "npm config set proxy http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and npm work properly. but not with ionic, there's error like shown above.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the Ionic CLI does not use the NPM proxy settings.
I solved this issue changing my system (Windows 10) http-proxy ENV variable.

Moreover, the error message seems to point that the protocol is not specified, only an IP is provided.
Try to change the proxy ENV variable from `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and see what happens (usually a shell restart is required to apply ENV variable changes).